# jQuery trigger event when an object is given a class

Tags: jquery, events, class, triggers, carousel

I am using a jQuery carousel, downloaded from here: http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm

It uses pagination, and applies a class called "active" to the current page number when the page number is clicked. I want to trigger an event to happen when this class is applied, since it also uses left and right arrows to apply the class to the current page number.

Here's the event that I want to be triggered when the class is applied:

```
$('.red').click(function() {
     $('#formred').attr('checked', 'checked');
 });
```

I have gotten it to work, but only when the page loads:

```
 if ($('.red').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.red').trigger('click');
 }
```

The first page number has the class applied by default, which is why this works when the page loads. I need this to happen as the class is applied to other page numbers.

Comment: I think you need to change your code technically. This because you actually want to trigger an event that must respond to another event being triggered.

Comment: This is the event that happens when I click on the page number. Is it not possible to trigger this event when the "active" class is applied to it as well?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** If you're just needing it on button clicks, and not for its `auto` feature, you could just place a `.delegate()` on the `.carousel` once it's available that listens for `click` events on the `'a[role=button]'` elements.

```
$('.carousel').delegate('a[role=button]', 'click', function() {

     // Because a button in the carousel was clicked, we know that
     //   one of the elements received the .active class. So we just
     //   need to find it.
     var $activeButton = $(this).closest('.carousel').find('.active');

     // Not sure how the .red class from your question factors in, but you
     //   can test the $activeButton to see if it has that class
     if( $activeButton.hasClass('red') ) {
         $('#formred').attr('checked', 'checked');
     }
});
```

Again, this would only work for click events on the buttons, not if it is set up to `auto` rotate. Not sure if this is what you're after.

---

If need be, there's a plugin called `livequery` that will run code on DOM modifications via jQuery.

http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

```
$('.someClass').livequery( function() {
    // your code
});
```

If you pass a second function argument, it will run when the class (or element) is removed.

```
$('.someClass').livequery( function() {
    // your code when adding
}, function() {
    // your code when removing
});
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this. But I don't think I want another plugin just for this. I'm sure it can be hand coded, but I just don't know how :)

Comment: Some people (people like me :-) consider "livequery" to be something to use with extreme caution anyway. It would work however; at least I think it would.

Comment: @Pointy: I totally agree, hence the *"If need be..."*. I probably should have stressed it more. It really should be a last resort.

Comment: @Robert - I updated my answer. On one hand, it seems like you want the addition of the `.active` class to trigger the event, but on the other hand, it seems that you're only using clicks to change the carousel. So why not use the click event? I added an example. There is no native cross browser compatible way to run code on DOM modifications.

Comment: @patrick dw - I am using the click event. But for what I'm doing, it can't only depend on the click. It needs to rely on the class change as well. In basic terms, is it possible to fire event when a class is added?

Comment: @Robert - When you say *"rely on class change as well"* if you mean coupled with the click event, there will be a solution. If you mean independent of the click so that it will fire without any other event, then no, there's no native cross-browser way to do this. The closest you'll get will be `livequery`.

Comment: @patrick dw - Yes, I mean coupled with the click event. With the carousel, the right and left arrows apply the class to the corresponding page number on click. When this class is applied, I want it to trigger an event.

Comment: @Robert - Ok, so if it is a click that triggers it, see the update I made at the top of my answer. It will fire the code when the right and left buttons, as well as the pagination buttons, are clicked. Since those are the click events that change the class, then it should work for you. Is there any other need to know which element received the `.active` class? If so, we should be able to traverse around and find out which button has `.active`.

Comment: Yes, there is a need to know which element has the "active" class. The click applies the class, but all I need to know is how to trigger an event when that class is applied. I have my event built, I just need it to listen to when the "active" class is applied. I think you're reading to far into the question. Don't worry about the carousel. It works as it should. I want to use the class is applies for something totally unrelated to the carousel.

Comment: @Robert - There is no native cross browser way to trigger an event based only on the adding of a class to an element. My point about the click is that it requires a click on one of the buttons to add the class, right? So that means we can detect a click on those buttons, and use that event to do what you want. That's my solution at the top. It seems that you need to know *which* button has the `.active` class. I'll update the solution to get that button.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you create a shared event handler, like:

```
function changePage( pageNum, nextprev ){
  if( nextprev ) pageNum = activePage + nextprev;

  // show the next page

  $('someElement').addClass('active');
}
```

And then set this event to both click and keydown:

```
$(...).keydown( function(){
  changePage( [1 or -1, depending on input], true );
});

$(...).click( function(){
  changePage( [clicked page], false );
});
```

Comment: I'm not worried about the carousel functionality. I need an event separate from the carousel to happen once the "active" class is applied the page number. That event is the second line in the code of my post.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is :

1-disable autoplay

2-create a setInterval that does a trigger('click') on the pagination of the carousel

3-and of course inside that you could do more then just trigger the slides